# Count files in Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm doing a mail merge from a Google sheet, and outputting the PDFs to a Google folder.
I'd like to be able to count the files, to ensure that they've all been merged.

I hacked a Google Apps Script:

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    function countfiles () {
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1-8Ek9gkm-_-YYYLK5_x7Y3Do_CzvmMfF");  
      var contents = folder.getFiles();

      var i=0;
      var contentsArray = [];

      while (contents.hasNext() && i < 5000) {
        var file = contents.next();
        contentsArray.push(file.getId());  //this is the array that will have the Id's of the first 4999 files.
        i++
      }
         sheet.clear();  

        // Insert Header
        sheet.appendRow("contents")
      }
```

I'm not sure how to output to my sheet the total count.

Paul

Comment: Do you want to output the number of files in a folder (ie. `i`) or the list of folder Id's (`contents`)?

Comment: Yes, just output the total number of files - (i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, take a look at the [Sheet's](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) `getRange()` and [Range's](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) `setValue()` methods. First, for `getRange()` we define a range in A1 notation (you can also define it [other ways](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)) to get a single cell as a Range object. Then we use the `setValue()` method on that cell to set the value!

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
function countfiles () {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1-8Ek9gkm-_-YYYLK5_x7Y3Do_CzvmMfF");  
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var i=0;
  var contentsArray = [];

  while (contents.hasNext() && i < 5000) {
    var file = contents.next();
    contentsArray.push(file.getId());  //this is the array that will have the Id's of the first 4999 files.
    i++
  }
  sheet.clear();  


  var range = sheet.getRange("A23"); //Get range object of single cell.
  range.setValue("Number: " + i); //set the value as count (i).

  // Insert Header
  sheet.appendRow("contents")
}
```